# I am working with an API and running into issues when trying to decode

Tags: swift, swiftui, decode

I am trying to decode from an API but I am getting this error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "search", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "search", intValue: nil) ("search").", underlyingError: nil))

I was able to get the data from the original games struct but I wasn't able to use it the way I wanted, it was limiting some of my access. So I tried to create a new struct so I can access everything but now I am unable to decode it here is all my code any help is appreciated.

```
struct Games: Decodable {
    
    var status: Int?
    var time: String?
    var games: Int?
    var skip: Int?
    var results: [GameResult]?
}

struct GameResult: Decodable {    
    
    var schedule: GameSchedule?
    var summary: String?
    var details: GameDetails?
    var status: String?
    var teams: TeamInfo?
    var lastUpdated: String?
    var gameId: Int?
    var venue: GameVenue?
    var odds: [GameOdds]?
}

struct GameSchedule: Decodable {
    
    var date: String?
    var tbaTime: Bool?
}

struct GameDetails: Decodable  {
    
    var league: String?
    var seasonType: String?
    var season: Int?
    var conferenceGame: Bool?
    var divisionGame: Bool?
}

struct GameVenue: Decodable {
    
    var name: String?
    var city: String?
    var state: String?
    var neutralSite: Bool?
}

struct GameOdds: Decodable {
    
    var spread: GameSpread?
    var moneyLine: GameMoneyLine?
    var total: GameTotal?
    var openDate: String?
    var lastUpdated: String?
}

struct GameSpread: Decodable {
    
    var open: OpenSpread?
    var current: CurrentSpread?
}

struct OpenSpread: Decodable {
    
    var away: Double?
    var home: Double?
    var awayOdds: Int?
    var homeOdds: Int?
    
}

struct CurrentSpread: Decodable {
    
    var away: Double?
    var home: Double?
    var awayOdds: Int?
    var homeOdds: Int?
}

struct GameMoneyLine: Decodable {
    
    var open: OpenMoney?
    var current: CurrentMoney?
}

struct OpenMoney: Decodable {
    
    var awayOdds: Int?
    var homeOdds: Int?
}

struct CurrentMoney: Decodable {
    
    var awayOdds: Int?
    var homeOdds: Int?
}

struct GameTotal: Decodable {
    
    var open: OpenTotal?
    var current: CurrentTotal?
}

struct OpenTotal: Decodable {
    
    var total: Double?
    var overOdds: Int?
    var underOdds: Int?
}

struct CurrentTotal: Decodable {
    
    var total: Double?
    var overOdds: Int?
    var underOdds: Int?
}

struct TeamInfo: Decodable {
    
    var away: AwayTeams?
    var home: HomeTeams?
}

struct AwayTeams: Decodable {
    
    var team: String?
    var location: String?
    var mascot: String?
    var abbreviation: String?
    var conference: String?
    var division: String?
}

struct HomeTeams: Decodable {
    
    var team: String?
    var location: String?
    var mascot: String?
    var abbreviation: String?
    var conference: String?
    var division: String?
}
```

Above is the original structs but this wouldn't allow me to access some of the values when I tried to assign results to use for UI so I tried to create this here:

```
class GameSearch: Decodable {
    
    var search = [Games]()
    var result = [GameResult]()
    var schedule = [GameSchedule]()
    var details = [GameDetails]()
    var venue = [GameVenue]()
    var odds = [GameOdds]()
    var gameSpread = [GameSpread]()
    var openSpread = [OpenSpread]()
    var currentSpread = [CurrentSpread]()
    var moneyLine = [GameMoneyLine]()
    var openMoney = [OpenMoney]()
    var currentMoney = [CurrentMoney]()
    var gameTotal = [GameTotal]()
    var openTotal = [OpenTotal]()
    var currentTotal = [CurrentTotal]()
    var teamInfo = [TeamInfo]()
    var away = [AwayTeams]()
    var home = [HomeTeams]()
}
```

Now I am unable to decode the data.

Here is my decoding process:

```
func getGames() {
        
        let headers = [
            "x-rapidapi-host": "sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "MY API KEY"
        ]
        
        let urlString = "https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games"
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        
        if url != nil {
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            
            let session = URLSession.shared
            
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                if error == nil {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let result = try decoder.decode(GameSearch.self, from: data!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            print(result)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the JSON that I am getting:

```
    {
  "status": 200,
  "time": "2022-02-08T20:09:45.316Z",
  "games": 60,
  "skip": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "schedule": {
        "date": "2022-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tbaTime": false
      },
      "summary": "Phoenix Suns @ Philadelphia 76ers",
      "details": {
        "league": "NBA",
        "seasonType": "regular",
        "season": 2021,
        "conferenceGame": false,
        "divisionGame": false
      },
      "status": "scheduled",
      "teams": {
        "away": {
          "team": "Phoenix Suns",
          "location": "Phoenix",
          "mascot": "Suns",
          "abbreviation": "PHX",
          "conference": "Western",
          "division": "Pacific"
        },
        "home": {
          "team": "Philadelphia 76ers",
          "location": "Philadelphia",
          "mascot": "76ers",
          "abbreviation": "PHI",
          "conference": "Eastern",
          "division": "Atlantic"
        }
      },
      "lastUpdated": "2022-02-08T20:09:12.610Z",
      "gameId": 268285,
      "venue": {
        "name": "Wells Fargo Center",
        "city": "Philadelphia",
        "state": "PA",
        "neutralSite": false
      },
      "odds": [
        {
          "spread": {
            "open": {
              "away": 1,
              "home": -1,
              "awayOdds": -110,
              "homeOdds": -110
            },
            "current": {
              "away": 1,
              "home": -1,
              "awayOdds": -110,
              "homeOdds": -115
            }
          },
          "moneyline": {
            "open": {
              "awayOdds": -107,
              "homeOdds": -113
            },
            "current": {
              "awayOdds": -101,
              "homeOdds": -119
            }
          },
          "total": {
            "open": {
              "total": 218,
              "overOdds": -110,
              "underOdds": -110
            },
            "current": {
              "total": 217.5,
              "overOdds": -110,
              "underOdds": -110
            }
          },
          "openDate": "2022-02-08T12:04:00.174Z",
          "lastUpdated": "2022-02-08T20:02:42.787Z"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Any help is appreciated thank you all!

Comment: Without seeing the JSON that you're trying to decode, there's no way to help debug this. The error is telling you that there's no value for "search" in the JSON. I would edit your question to include the JSON and/or paste the JSON into [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) and compare your models.

Comment: `print(error)` => `print("Decoding failed \(error) with response string: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")`, and show us what you really received. Because it could be that your model is wrong, that you assumed the response from the API, but it's not that (because of bad request, server error, etc.). We can't help you without knowing the response.

Comment: Thank you guys I updated it including the JSON data @jnpdx

Comment: Thank you guys I updated it including the JSON data @Larme

Comment: According to the JSON the root object is `Games`, not `GameSearch`

Comment: You should be decoding using `decoder.decode(Games.self, from: data!)`. `GameSearch` doesn't match your JSON at all. But, in your question, you say that led to errors when you tried to use the data in your UI -- perhaps that's the direction you should go with your question.